# Which technology should I use to be able to store different structured data about a set of objects?

Tags: solr, nosql

The problem: I have data about different entities that I get from various 'show' commands. What is the best way to store this data so I can query them to make decision based on their values.

My solution: Parse the 'show' commands in python and dump the data different objects in solr and query using their individual keys and having some python code use the data retrieved to come up with a decision ?

Is Solr the right technology to use in this case ?
-- Param

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use the solr to achieve the same. You can get the data from different entities and add to solr by creating a single document.

You can define your single document\entity in solr's schema.xml file.

If you are getting the data from database , you can think of using the DIH functionality of Solr.

Here is a link for the same
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

You need to know some thing like which all keys you would be searching should be marked as indexed, and which should be marked as stored. It all would depend on your requirement.